# VBA: Excel Data to MS Word FormField

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to copy data from an Excel document to a Word document. My excel doc has 4 columns and I've set my word document to have 4 formfields named after the Excel column names. When I run my code I get the following error: `Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`. The line where I'm erroring out is highlighted with ** **.

In my private sub I defined and set my variable `wdFormField` so I'm confused why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit


Sub Checklist()
Dim WDApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim mywdRange As Word.Range
Dim r As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim dDate As Date
Dim strNumber As String

Set WDApp = New Word.Application
With WDApp
.Visible = True
.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1")
m = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For r = 3 To m
If Range("A" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

Set myDoc = WDApp.Documents.Add(Template:="X:\abcde.docx\")
Copy_Cell_To_Form_Field myDoc, Range("A" & r).Value, "Text1"
Copy_Cell_To_Form_Field myDoc, Range("B" & r).Value, "Text2"
Copy_Cell_To_Form_Field myDoc, Range("C" & r).Value, "Text3"
Copy_Cell_To_Form_Field myDoc, Range("D" & r).Value, "Text4"

myDoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="X:\abcde.docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
myDoc.Close
End If
Next r

End Sub
Private Sub Copy_Cell_To_Form_Field(doc As Word.Document, cellValue As Variant, formFieldName As String)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wdFormField As Word.FormField

    
    Set wdFormField = Nothing
    i = 1
    ' the next line gives me: Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set
    While i <= doc.FormFields.Count And wdFormField Is Nothing
        If doc.FormFields(i).Name = formFieldName Then Set wdFormField = doc.FormFields(i)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    
    If Not wdFormField Is Nothing Then
        wdFormField.Result = cellValue
    Else
        MsgBox "Form field bookmark " & formFieldName & " doesn't exist in " & doc.Name
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code, including:

- X:\abcde.docx\ is not a valid filename. Moreover, a docx file isn't
  really a template.
- Having defined wdFormField As Word.FormField you can't set it to Nothing.

Try the following:

```
Sub Checklist()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Dim xlSht As Worksheet, r As Long, c As Long
Set xlSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  For r = 3 To xlSht.Range("A" & xlSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If xlSht.Range("A" & r).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
      Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(Template:="X:\abcde.docx")
      With wdDoc
        For c = 1 To 4
          If .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & c) Then
            .Bookmarks("Text" & c).Range.Fields(1).Result.Text = xlSht.Cells(r, c).Text
          Else
            MsgBox "Form field bookmark 'Text" & c & "' doesn't exist in:" & vbCr & _
              .AttachedTemplate.FullName
          End If
        Next
        .SaveAs2 Filename:="X:\abcde.docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close
      End With
    End If
  Next r
  .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. On first trying your code I error out here: `For r = 3 To xlSht.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. The Error is: VBA compile error: Method or data member not found

Comment: It works fine for me... Besides which that line is mostly your own code - just used more efficiently!

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, interesting! The error highlights `.Rows.` which is odd. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The issue is because `Word.Application` doesn't have a `Rows` property.

Comment: Row reference fixed.

Comment: And your `.Bookmarks("Text" & c).Exists` needs to be changed to .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & c) then

Comment: Unfortunately, I now get an error that says: `Object Variable or With Block variable not set` for this line: `If .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & c) Then`

Comment: Well, given that I error out with your `.Bookmarks("Text" & c).Exist` but when I change it to `.Bookmarks("Text" & c).Exists` I don't error out, I'd say its warranted.

Comment: haha thats my bad, I meant .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & c); either way, my code works with the .Exists before the (). If yours works how you put it then more power to you.

Comment: Make up your mind. You previously said «I now get an error that says: Object Variable or With Block variable not set for this line: If .Bookmarks.Exists("Text" & c) Then».